# DataGridViewComboBoxColumn does not render with custom datasource

Tags: c#, combobox, datagridcomboboxcolumn

Using information from this thread I've attempted to setup and dynamically populate a datagridviewcomboboxolumn with options. My debugger shows no errors, but the combobox does not render.

```
//setup combobox
List<combo_automation_option> combo = new List<combo_automation_option>();
combo.Add(new combo_automation_option { id = "0", value = "None" });
combo.Add(new combo_automation_option { id = "*.0.5", value = "Once every 5 minutes" });

dgv_col_automation.HeaderText = "Automation";
dgv_col_automation.Name = "dgv_jobs_col_automation";
dgv_col_automation.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
dgv_col_automation.DataSource = combo;
dgv_col_automation.ValueMember = "id";
dgv_col_automation.DataPropertyName = "value";

jobs_datagrid.Columns.Add(dgv_col_automation);
```

It rendered fine when I used the settings below to setup my combo box:

```
//setup combobox                        
dt_col_automation.HeaderText = "Automation";
dt_col_automation.Name = "dgv_jobs_col_automation";
dt_col_automation.Items.AddRange(
        "Once every 5 minutes",
        "Once every 10 minutes",
        "Once every 15 minutes",
        "Once every 30 minutes",
        "Once every hour",
        "Once every 2 hours",
        "Once every 3 hours",
        "Once every 4 hours",
        "Once every 5 hours",
        "Once every 6 hours",
        "Once every 7 hours",
        "Once every 8 hours",
        "Once every 9 hours",
        "Once every 10 hours",
        "Once every 11 hours",
        "Once every 12 hours",
        "1",
        "2",
        "3",
        "4",
        "5",
        "6",
        "7",
        "8",
        "9",
        "10",
        "11",
        "12",
        "13",
        "14",
        "15",
        "16",
        "17",
        "18",
        "19",
        "20",
        "21",
        "22",
        "23",
        "24"
    );
```

I've a public struct that looks like this:

```
public struct combo_automation_option { 
   public string id;
   public string value;
}
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 2):

Data binding doesn't work on class/struct fields even if thery're public.

You should use properties instead e.g.:

```
public struct combo_automation_option { 
   public string id {get; set;}
   public string value {get; set;}
}
```

Furthermore, if you want to show something else (e.g. the value) instead of the id in the combobox, set also the `DisplayMember` property.

BTW, other few suggestions:

- structs should be used only if really necessary; use classes instead
- you're not following the usual c# naming convenction that is: always camel casing (no underscore) and only struct/classes, methods, properties must start with the a capital letter.

Comment: Updating the struct like you suggested fixed my issue, but Visual Studio says that DataGridViewComboBoxColum does not contain a definition for DisplayProperty (Haris Hasan must have deleted his post, I cannot find it.)

Also I cannot get the value of each row for that column (which is currently 0) to populate "None" as the pre-select item. I'm new to c#.

Comment: @atwellpub: Of course, sorry I made a mistake: I had written "DisplayProperty member" instead of "DisplayMember property" (so the correct name is DisplayMember). Now is fixed.

Comment: @atwellpub: about your second problem... Have you already added some rows to the datagrid? If so, just loop over the collection: `foreach(DataGridViewRow row in jobs_datagrid.Rows)` and set the value doing: `row.Cells[yourComboColumnIndex].Value = "0";`